# Custom search for Custom Post Type is not working

Tags: wordpress, search, customization, custom-post-type

I created a custom search functionality for a custom post type. It works well before. Now search results redirects to the default WordPress search and do not get the defined template (archive-search.php).

**Note:** It seems this happens because of some Woocommerce actions and filters

`functions.php` code for search result template

```
// Custom Search Template
function template_chooser($template)   
{    
    global $wp_query;
    $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');

    if( $wp_query->is_search && $post_type == 'client' )   
    {
        return locate_template('archive-search.php');
    }   
    return $template;   
}
add_filter('template_include', 'template_chooser');
```

form code

```
<form role="search" action="<?php echo site_url('/'); ?>" method="get">
<div class="mb-3">
    <label for="company" class="form-label">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="s" class="form-control" />
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="book" />
<input type="submit" class="btn" value="Search" />
```

`archive-search.php` template

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'book',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    's' => $_GET['s'],
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
);
$books = new WP_Query( $args );
if($books->have_posts()):
    echo '<ul class="list-unstyled">';
    while($books->have_posts()): $books->the_post();
?>

    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

<?php
    endwhile;
    echo '</ul>';
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone facing the same issue, it is due to a conflict between Woocommerce action hook.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with WooCommerce and using 'template_include' filter to call a custom search template conditionally for a custom post type. The 'add_filter' documentation shows that a priority value can be set in order to modify the execution order.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/

Modifying your code below to add a value for the priority should work.

Try to change from the below:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'template_chooser' );
```

to the following:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'template_chooser', 11 );
```

Making sure to use a value higher than 10.